# How to change the permalink structure in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.1.x

I have a page which structure is like this:

```
root
   ..prod
      page.php
```

I can access it with `http://localhost/index.php?id=41`.

But i want to acess it like this:

```
http://localhost/prod/title-of-page
```

How to do that?

Comment: Check out [RealURL: speaking paths for TYPO3](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/realurl) - it's now also compatible to TYPO3 Version 7.x.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RealURL](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/realurl) or [CoolURI](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cooluri) extension - they are so old and well known that when you write `typo3 friendly urls` in your search engine you finding only these two.

Note: personally I prefer RealURL